# Program crashes when trying to access file, fstream --C++

Tags: c++, fstream, crash-reports

I am making a user database. When I try to open the `"dataBase.txt"` which holds all of the users and passwords, the console pops up (which should happen since it is a console application) but it says that the program has already complete. When I close it, my computer tell me that the program had crashed. The function is saved in a class.

After some debugging the code seems to crash at `ifstream fin("dataBase.txt");`

**No error is returned from the compiler.**

**The code for the function called is:**

```
void User_Psw::UserCheck()
{
    // read from the database
    ifstream fin("dataBase.txt");

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin >> Usernames[sizeOfDatabase] >> Password[sizeOfDatabase];
        sizeOfDatabase++; //The Number of lines in .txt
    }

    // rest of the program
    cout << "Username: ";
    cin >> username;

    getNameIndex();

    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> password;

    if(!PasswordMatches())
    {
        cout << "Access denied";
    }
}
```

**I can add more code snippets if asked.**

Comment: I think you have more errors than that. Look at `fin`. If all else fails, read the documentation!

Comment: How are `Usernames` and `Passwords` declared? Also `while (!fin.eof())` is probably not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Why do things like `Usernames[sizeOfDatabase]` make me think somewhere out there is a vector/deque/array/fixed-array that is about to have the memory one element past its allotted size get stomped?

Comment: Well I call `Usernames` as `std::vector<std::string> Usernames;` and `Password` as `std::vector<std::string> Password;` And I think that `while (!fin.eof())` is checking the number of lines in the file and then saving it to the variable `sizeOfDatabase` which I can then use as an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `fin.eof()` to control a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). That function is only useful after a read has failed.

A likely reason for the crash, however, is that you are assigning to `Usernames[sizeOfDatabase]`, which may be beyond `Usernames.capacity()`. The canonical way to append and item to a [**`std::vector`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is to call [**`push_back()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Since your containers are `std::vector<std::string>`, this is a better approach...

```
std::string username, password;
while (fin >> username >> password)
{
    Usernames.push_back(username);
    Passwords.push_back(password);
    ++sizeOfDatabase;
}
```

Of course, if you want to know the number of usernames or passwords once the file has been read, you can call `Usernames.size()` (which should be the same as `Passwords.size()`); this may obviate the need to keep `sizeOfDatabase`.

Personally, I would use a single container for usernames and [(salted, hashed) passwords](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html), rather than two separate containers; either [`std::map<std::string, std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or perhaps [`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), making the password lookup nice and quick per username.

Comment: Thank You!! that was the fix. So this was a better approach because it would just keep on adding a new new variables to the vars `username` and `password`?

Comment: Correct, it also stops you reading off the end of the file. Now, ***please*** tell me you are not storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: Trust me, this is not for some huge project. I am doing this as a learning experience. They are stored in .txt right now, and later on I hope on learning how to encrypt them, perhaps with the function `crypt` if I know it right. Right now I am just trying to make it where you can have an account with your high score saved on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by adding this to the constructor of your `ifstream` as you haven't specified you want the file opened for input:

```
ifstream fin( "dataBase.txt",  ifstream::in );

if( !fin.good() )
{
    cout << "Failed to open database file." << endl;
    return;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/ for additional literature.

Comment: I made the `ifstrea::in` change and then put in the check to see if the file was good or not, but when I run the program no line pops up saying `Failed to open database file`. So I assume it is good but the program still crashes.

Comment: @ponger3d if `fin.good()` fails and you get the error message then perhaps you don't have access to the directory? I would first solve the issue causing the access to the file.